# Java Swing--- display nothing when runs the program

Tags: java, swing

I am a new learner of Java Swing. I am trying to draw some shapes.

### But when I run the following codes, I can't see the graph at all.

Can't understanding why, Could someone help me with it? Thanks a lot!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Draw 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                DrawFrame frame = new DrawFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class DrawFrame extends JFrame
{
    public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 400;

    public DrawFrame()
    {
        setTitle("DrawTest");
        setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

        DrawComponent component = new DrawComponent();
        add(component);
    }
}

class DrawComponent extends JComponent
{
    public void painComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle2D rec = new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 200, 150);
        g2.draw(rec);

        Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double();
        ellipse.setFrame(rec);
        g2.draw(ellipse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `painComponent` a typo, or is this your actual code? It should be `paintComponent`.

Comment: @Ash I am so careless! got it! Thanks so much!

Comment: just added as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the supplied code, the `paintComponent` method has an error in the name:

```
public void painComponent(Graphics g)
```

So it's not actually overriding the method from the superclass. You can add the @Override annotation so that the compiler will give an error if the method doesn't actually override anything, for example:

```
@Override
public void painComponent(Graphics g)
```